# SAS Dataset : Counting observation that match an IF condition

Tags: if-statement, sas, dataset, conditional-statements, counting

Here is a very basic question, but I'm unable to find an easy way to do it. 
I have a dataset that references different highschools and students :

`Highschool    Students   Sexe 
      A            1         m
      A            2         m
      A            3         m
      A            4         f
      A            5         f
      B            1         m
      B            2         m`

And I'd like to create two new variables that count the number of male and female in each schools :

`Highschool    Students   Sexe    Nb_m     Nb_f
      A            1         m      1         0
      A            2         m      2         0
      A            3         m      3         0
      A            4         f      3         1
      A            5         f      3         2
      B            1         m      1         0
      B            2         m      2         0`

And I can finally extract the last line with the total that would look like this :

`Highschool    Students   Sexe    Nb_m     Nb_f
      A            5         f      3         2
      B            2         m      2         0`

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to sort your dataset by *Highschool*:

```
proc sort data = your_dataset;
    by Highschool;
run;
```

then you use

  -
  *retain*
  to not reset Nb_m and Nb_f at every record;

  -
  *last*
  function and
  *output*
  statement to print only the last observation for every school.

```
data new_dataset;
    set your_dataset;
    by Highschool;
    retain Nb_m Nb_f;
    if Sexe = 'm' then
        Nb_m + 1;
    else
        Nb_f + 1;
    if last.Highschool then do;
        Students = Nb_m + Nb_f;
        output;
        Nb_m = 0;
        Nb_f = 0;
    end;
run;
```

Comment: Great ! Thanks a lot Matteo. 
One more question : why do you reset Nb_m and Nb_f in the do statement ?

Comment: Because if I don't reset them in the next Highschool I will retain the number of males and females in the previous one: in your case it will count the 'A' males/females correctly, but it will return Nb_m=7 and Nb_f=5 for school 'B'.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in a single `PROC SQL` step...

Also, I don't think you really need the value of `Sexe` from the last row.

```
proc sql ;
  create table want as
  select Highschool, 
         sum(case when Sexe = 'f' then 1 else 0 end) as Nb_f,
         sum(case when Sexe = 'm' then 1 else 0 end) as Nb_m,
         Nb_f + Nb_m as Students
  group by Highschool
  order by Highschool ;
quit ;
```

Comment: you're right, I don't need this information. I'm not used to SQL, but this seems really elegant. Would this work by adding condition as well ? ex : when Sexe = 'f' & condition = "1" then... ?

Comment: Yes, you could add any additional logic into the `case when`; `case when (condition[s]) then true_val else false_val end`.